# How include comment and post count of user in this custom query

Tags: comments, count

This is a listing of members with pagination

```
<?php
$total = "SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY user_nicename DESC";

$totalposts = $wpdb->get_results($total, OBJECT);

$ppp = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));

$wp_query->found_posts = count($totalposts);

$wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $ppp);

$on_page = intval(get_query_var('paged'));

if($on_page == 0){ $on_page = 1; }

$offset = ($on_page-1) * $ppp;

$wp_query->request = "SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY user_nicename DESC LIMIT $ppp OFFSET $offset";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request, OBJECT);
?>

<?php if ($pageposts):
shuffle($pageposts);
array_rand($pageposts); ?>

<?php foreach ($pageposts as $author):
// Get user data
$curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);
// Get link to author page
$user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
// Set default avatar (values = default, wavatar, identicon, monsterid)
$avatar = 'wavatar';
?>

<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

If I can include avatar, I think I can show post count and comment count too.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you used a direct SQL statement rather than the WP_User_Query object? http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

Comment: Also you have a zero acceptance rate, could you review your previous questions and accept any correct answers?

Answer (score 1):

There's the [count_user_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) function which will give you a count of posts for a given user id. From a quick look through the Codex, I don't see a similar function to return a comment count. But after looking at the [source for count_user_posts](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/user.php#L146), I think it would be easy to adapt the code to count comments instead.